# Automatic wakeup immediately after hibernation

Tags: linux, systemd, hibernate, zorin

I using Zorin OS Core 12.2 in dual boot with Windows 10.

I used the command  `sudo systemctl hibernate` to hibernate.

The system goes to hibernation like for few seconds and automatically wakes up without any intervention.I disabled the EHC1, EHC2 and XHC in /proc/acpi/wakeup. The made those changes permanent.

I encounter the same problem in suspend state too.

> 1. swap is also more than the RAM size
> 2. secured boot is disabled
> 3. tried pm-utils, that too not working